# How do I create a boolean function that will determine if a group of radio buttons have all been selected and return a message box to the user?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I was given an assignment to create a program for an airline in which allows the user to select their seat. After each seat is selected, I am suppose to set the corresponding buttons array element’s Enabled property to False. Once all of the available seats are taken, I am required to create a Boolean function to check if there are any seats available. If all seats are taken, then a message box should pop up and tell the user this information.

The problem is I can't seem to get the message box to show up once all of the seats are taken. Please help me figure this out. I have attached my code below. Thanks!

```
Public Class Form1
Private availableSeats(7) As Boolean
Private buttons(7) As RadioButton
Private truth As Boolean


Private Sub UpdateSeatButtons()
    For x As Integer = 0 To 7
        If availableSeats(x) = False Then
            buttons(x).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function CheckForAvailable() As Boolean
    Dim seat As Boolean
    For Each seat In availableSeats
        If seat = True Then
            truth = True
            Return truth
        End If
    Next
    truth = False
    Return truth
End Function

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        buttons(i) = New RadioButton
    Next
    buttons(0) = seat10ARadioButton
    buttons(1) = seat11ARadioButton
    buttons(2) = seat12ARadioButton
    buttons(3) = seat13ARadioButton
    buttons(4) = seat10BRadioButton
    buttons(5) = seat11BRadioButton
    buttons(6) = seat12BRadioButton
    buttons(7) = seat13BRadioButton


    For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        buttons(i).Checked = False
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Caption As String = "Seat Update"
    Dim boxButtons As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.OK
    Dim Result As DialogResult
    For z As Integer = 0 To 7
        Dim Message As Integer = z
        If buttons(z).Checked Then
            availableSeats(z) = False
            Result = MessageBox.Show(Message, Caption, boxButtons)
        Else
            availableSeats(z) = True
        End If


    Next
    UpdateSeatButtons()
    CheckForAvailable()
    If truth = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("This flight is full", "No seats available", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

End Class

Below is a set of instructions my professor gave me:

> Instructions
>
> In this case, you will create a Visual Basic solution that allows the
>   Island Breezes Sea Planes airline to assign seats to passengers. This
>   program demonstrates the use of parallel one-dimensional arrays.  One
>   array is used to represent the availability of each seat. The other
>   array is used to manage the RadioButton controls on the form.  It
>   introduces the technique of using an array of RadioButton objects.
>   Here are instructions on how to design and code this project:
>
> Step 1: Create the Project: Create a Visual Basic Project using the
>   project name “AirplaneSeating”.
>
> Step 2 – Design the Form: Design the form as shown in Figure 1.  You
>   will need two button controls, one textbox, one group box, eight radio
>   buttons, one picture box, and two label controls.
>
> Step 3 – Declare the form-level arrays: Declare an array of Boolean
>   values to indicate the availability of each seat:
>       Private availableSeats(7) As Boolean Declare an object array as type RadioButton:
>       Private buttons(7) As RadioButton
>
> Step 3 – Add code in the Form’s Load event to initialize the arrays:
>   Each object in the buttons array must be initialized to be a
>   RadioButton object. In the Form’s Load event, write a loop to
>   initialize each array element using this syntax: buttons(i) = New
>   RadioButton
>
> After this loop, load each individual radio button into an array
>   position, using this syntax (in this example, the first  radio button
>   control’s name is seat10ARadioButton, and it is being loaded into the
>   first object array position):
>           buttons(0) = seat10ARadioButton Do this for each radio button control.
>
> Finally, write a loop to set the Checked property of all of the
>   buttons array elements to False.
>
> Step 4 – Create a sub procedure for showing seat availability on the
>   form: Create a sub procedure named UpdateSeatButtons that will loop
>   through the availableSeats array.  If an element in the availableSeats
>   array equals False, set the corresponding buttons array element’s
>   Enabled property to False to visually indicate that this seat is no
>   longer available.
>
> Step 5 – Create a function for determining if there are any seats
>   still available: Create a Boolean function named CheckForAvailable
>   that will loop through the c array to determine if there are any seats
>   still available. If there is at least one seat available, return a
>   True value; otherwise, return False.
>
> Step 6 – Add code in the Confirm Seat button’s Click event to update
>   the seating chart: Loop through the buttons array to determine which
>   button was selected.  Set the corresponding availableSeats array
>   element to False.  Then call the UpdateSeatButtons sub procedure to
>   update the visual seating chart.
>
> Call the CheckForAvailable function to determine whether you should
>   display a message indicating that the flight is full.
>
> Step 7 – Finish up:
>
> Be sure to add the code for the Exit button.
>
> Step 8:  Save and run Save all files, then start the application. 
>   Test the program using various selections.  Figure 2 shows a sample
>   run of this program, with the user’s choices shown. Notice that the
>   unavailable seats are grayed.

**Thank you so much for all of your help! I was able to solve the problem. I have attached my final code below. Thanks again!**

```
Public Class Form1
Private availableSeats(7) As Boolean
Private buttons(7) As RadioButton
Private truth As Boolean


Private Sub UpdateSeatButtons()
    For z As Integer = 0 To 7
        If availableSeats(z) = False Then
            buttons(z).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function CheckForAvailable() As Boolean
    Dim seat As Boolean
    For Each seat In availableSeats
        If seat = True Then
            truth = True
            Return truth
        End If
    Next
    truth = False
    Return truth
End Function

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For z As Integer = 0 To 7
        buttons(z) = New RadioButton
    Next
    buttons(0) = seat10ARadioButton
    buttons(1) = seat11ARadioButton
    buttons(2) = seat12ARadioButton
    buttons(3) = seat13ARadioButton
    buttons(4) = seat10BRadioButton
    buttons(5) = seat11BRadioButton
    buttons(6) = seat12BRadioButton
    buttons(7) = seat13BRadioButton


    For z As Integer = 0 To 7
        buttons(z).Checked = False
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Caption As String = "Seat Update"
    Dim boxButtons As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.OK
    Dim Result As DialogResult
    For z As Integer = 0 To 7
        Dim Message As Integer = z
        If buttons(z).Checked Then
            availableSeats(z) = False
            Result = MessageBox.Show(Message, Caption, boxButtons)
        ElseIf buttons(z).Enabled = False Then
            availableSeats(z) = False
        Else
            availableSeats(z) = True
        End If


    Next
    UpdateSeatButtons()
    CheckForAvailable()
    If truth = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("This flight is full", "No seats available", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Why are there radio buttons each used twice when setting the buttons array?

Comment: Are you talking about buttons(i) & buttons(z)? Should I only do one?

Comment: `CheckAvailable` is partially broke.  Set a breakpoint and debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop add *buttons(z).Enabled = False*:

```
For z As Integer = 0 To 7
    Dim Message As Integer = z
    If buttons(z).Checked Or buttons(z).Enabled = False Then
        If buttons(z).Checked Then
            Result = MessageBox.Show(Message, Caption, boxButtons)
        End If
        availableSeats(z) = False
    Else
        availableSeats(z) = True
    End If


Next
```

Every time you press the button you set the *availableSeats* array to true except for the checked one including of course your disabled ones.

EDIT

Initialize *availableSeats* to true:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 7
    availableSeats(i) = True
Next
```

and

```
For z As Integer = 0 To 7
    Dim Message As Integer = z
    If buttons(z).Checked Then
        Result = MessageBox.Show(Message, Caption, boxButtons)
        availableSeats(z) = False

        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

valter

Comment: That worked! However, now every time I push the button every seat that I have selected previously comes up as a separate message box. I need it to only have the seat number I selected. Help?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a number of changes to your code. You do not need to create the buttons and availableSeats arrays; just use the controls themselves. This approach eliminates setting and testing for available seats. I created a new Sub that handles all RadioButton click events and disables the associated control. Let me know if I have misunderstood the requirements or need help interpreting my code.

```
Private Function CheckForAvailable() As Boolean
    For Each ctl As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is RadioButton Then
            If ctl.Enabled Then Return True ' could have tested for Checked too
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   ' no need to initialize anything here
End Sub

Private Sub SeatClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click, RadioButton2.Click, RadioButton3.Click, RadioButton4.Click, RadioButton5.Click, RadioButton6.Click, RadioButton7.Click, RadioButton8.Click
    If CType(sender, RadioButton).Checked Then
        If CType(sender, RadioButton).Checked Then
            CType(sender, RadioButton).Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim boxButtons As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.OK
    If Not CheckForAvailable() Then
        MessageBox.Show("This flight is full", "No seats available", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm required to use arrays unfortunately. I will edit my original post to include all of the instructions he gave us.